# What to do about rotten sheathing behind deck ledger

Tags: repair, deck, ledger

My deck and patio door were improperly flashed. I've discovered that the osb sheathing between the ledger and the rim joist is rotten. Assuming the rim joist is still sound (I've not yet confirmed this to be the case), it's it all right to have a space between the ledger and the rim joist? Does that put to much tension on the upper ledger boards? Should I drive home sort of plywood spacers to fill some of the space the sheathing used to occupy?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Similar situation here. Why not just cut a clean line and add new OSB instead of leaving the dry rot and gap? There should be some building wrap, tar paper, of flashing there too.

I'm no finish carpenter but I did patch up the rotted OSB and cover it with tar paper. Now I need to add a new ledger board and flashing for the new deck.

[image]